# Can I use "gem devise" and Michael Hartl rails tutorial authentication system together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

I have already finished Michael Hartl's rails tutorial and now I have a rails app which users can sign up with their information.

I want to add "Sign up with Facebook and Twitter" feature to my app. But when I tried it just usage of omniauth, I have got some problems.

Now I want to try it with using gem `devise` and gem `omniauth` together for adding "Sign up with Facebook and Twitter" feature, without changing my authentication system.

Is it possible? I will be also grateful if you advice different methods for adding omniauth.

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use Devise and a custom authentication system together.

However I don't recommend you to implement two different authentication systems. It makes your app only unnecessarily complicated.

Here is a great [Tutorial](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview) on how to use Omniauth together with Devise.

Hope this helps!

Happy coding :)

Comment: How do you propose using both Devise and a custom auth system?

Comment: If you have a devise session controller to authenticate and your custom one, you have implemented both authentication systems. You just have to set a session cookie and that's it for a pretty simple authentication. But as I already said, it would make the app just unnecessarily complicated and I doesn't bring any advantages.